# MVC - зачем и почему

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, php, mvc

Все рекомендуют учить/использовать/молиться на MVC.

Сталкиваюсь с ним в основном в джумле, то развилась аллергия на нубское применение: например, зашел я в файл `template.php`, а там написано:

```
<?php $this->view->printHTML(); ?>
```

И соответственно я ищу эту функцию по файлам, в ней подключаются еще три файла, require в цикле и тому подобное. Я понимаю, что это не "pure MVC", но когда шаблон используется везде, даже если основной фреймворк к этому не приспособлен + провоцирует на такую кашу из *лишних* файлов, меня это настораживает.

И собственно вопрос: всю жизнь, как недавно выяснилось, использовал [фасад](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29) либо простую пару код(функция/класс/require)+шаблон для простых  модулей. Для пары кодер+верстальщик второе мне кажется идеальным.

Чем MVC лучше и есть ли более адекватные паттерны *для командной работы*?
Или все-таки "MVC" - просто очередная крутая аббревиатура для непрямого массажа мозга работодателям?

Comment: Тема оооочень холиварна, по поводу "идиотского" использования MVC - это не проблема MVC - это проблема квалификации и(или) больного мозга разработчика :)

Comment: Проблема скорее в том, что такое количество способов идиотского использования я наблюдал *только* с MVC =) Особенно, когда при этом его пытаются скооперировать с сlass-template'ом.

Comment: только с MVC наблюдал потому, что, цитирую "везде и все рекомендуют учить/использовать/молиться на MVC" :)

Соответственно все стараются писать с его использованием, даже не понимая - зачем вообще оно надо и как написать **нормально**.

Comment: То же можно отнести к термину ООП (просто все уже привыкли)

Comment: Так чистый ООП тоже не всегда для задачи подходит. Но такая аналогия в принципе мне нравится, потому что везде суют ооп те же люди с тем же результатом)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ёлка-зеленки, что я тут читаю!?

Ребят. Если вы сталкиваетесь с плохим кодом и в нём плохой программист написал

> И, соответственно, я ищу эту функцию по
>   файлам, в ней подключаются ещё три
>   файла, require в цикле и тому
>   подобное.

Это не проблема Архитектуры MVC — это проблема кривых рук, тупой головы и неправильного понимания.

MVC — это очень удобно.

Если интересно узнать про временные рамки создания, то с помощью YII Framework админку для сайта можно сделать за срок примерно от часа до 3 часов. Пусть она будет не «Ах, как красиво», зато полностью функциональна.

MVC — это круто!

От программиста, при условии, что он юзает Framework, нужно только логическое представление его проекта и понимание принципов архитектуры MVC.

Для большинства фреймворков, первым демо для нубов делают создание  "БЛОГА", для чего? Ну обычно, в хорошем случае, почти все веб-девелоперы делают свой блог, а тут раз — и поднять его на каком-либо фреймворке за 10-30 минут, вааще круть. На нём будет и проверка на вводимые символы путем небольших манипуляций, и проверка на заполнение и прочее, прочее, прочее.

Кто сталкивался, опять же повторюсь, с нубовскими кодами ребят, вырвите эти руки у тех, кто писал, а на архитектуру не ругайтесь. Если вы не прочувствовали её или не поняли - это не значит что это плохо. Скорее, Вы не компетентны в вопросе, а не архитектура, ведь на ней сейчас разрабатываются огромные проекты, в том числе и высоконагруженные.

Плюсы MVC можно перечислять долго, минусы тоже есть.

Допустим, долго вы будете писать кеширование на вашем ресурсе? Ну, наверное, потратите точно день-два, это при хорошем стечении обстоятельств, и то, не уверен, ведь применять его нужно на весь код. 
А в MVC вы просто добавляете, дай боже, 2—10 строк в код и радуетесь, что ваш ресурс меньше долбит БД, больше отправляет кеша пользователю, все довольны, хозяин рад. Сервер отдыхает.

Писать и расписывать я могу долго, но долбить в стену — это неправильно. В стену нубы долбятся, я очень надеюсь, что их на данном ресурсе всё же оооочень маленькое кол-во.

Учите матчасть, читайте про архитектуру MVC, учитесь, и пытайтесь понять на примерах!

Удачи.

Comment: кто поставил +1 ? спасибо хочу сказать :)

Comment: Эх) Тоже бы высказался, да жаль обед заканчивается. MVC это, конечно, true, но если уж речь о php, а значит о вебе, то в реальной жизни, где в приложении изменяется лишь часть контента от страницы к странице на порядок ловчее использовать так называемый HMVC. Усё. Обед окончен:-(

Comment: @Виталий Кустов красиво написал :)

Comment: Есть мнение, что вы любой качественный код называете "MVC" и просто не сталкивались с грамотными реализациями без его использования)

Тут просто чего случилось. Пиарили-пиарили jquery, я попробовал, мне понравилось - да, ощутимое облегчение, повышение скорости, меньше нервов на кроссбраузерность уходит.

Но еще дольше пиарят MVC, я попробовал, посмотрел существующие примеры и не увидел принципиальных различий. Есть MVC (yii vs joomla), есть не MVC (bitrix vs phpbb). В каждой паре есть хороший и плохой пример. Так, собственно, почему советуют именно ее учить, а не писать хороший код?)

Comment: @Sh4dow это вопрос к кому сейчас?

Качественный код - это качественный код. 
ООП  - это ООП.
MVC - это архитектура разработки - это не касается красивого кода. Это просто есть.
Красивый код должен закладываться изначально у программиста, если он будет писать в ООП без табуляции то грош ему цена,код должен быть читаемым. Понять как работает сайт на MVC новому программисту много проще, чем ковыряться в куче файлов php написанных на самопальном движке.

Comment: Вот теперь ответ понятен. И заодно понятно, почему мне это не понятно) Мне просто не хватало понимания, что это для "постоянно развивающихся" продуктов при отсутствии нормальной команды и нормального руководства.

*Я считаю, что код должен работать. Продукт должен быть законченным и работать хорошо. Лучшие вещи(не только код) всегда создавались 1 человеком или под его полным контролем, и "новый программист" обязан разобраться в коде, а не "старый программист" писать для нового. Из олдового - fallout сделан 1 человеком с незначительной помощью. Из нового - Apple)*

Но это только мое мнение :)

Comment: Вообще круто писать на MVC архитектуре, использовать SVN, и несколько программистов в одном проекте. Один старший который аккуратно соединят это все воедино и сам пишет свои части. в общем работа в команде - это всегда круто, полезно и очень быстро развиваешься профессионально.

Comment: Красиво можно писать и без ООП, на функциях)))

Comment: И это тоже правда, особенно с появлением closures.

Answer (score 4):

Отвечу безотносительно языка и платформы касательно целесообразности MVC как такового. Я недавно участвовал в разработке приложения (типа виртуальной клавиатуры), практически весь функционал которого сводился к пользовательскому интерфейсу. Приложение писалось на WPF с использованием MVVM (это не MVC, но достаточно близко к этому). Почему был выбран подход на основе MVVM? Потому что это очень сильно облегчает тестирование: сведение вида к минимуму позволяет тестировать отдельно модель и контроллер. Тестирование вида ограничивается внешним просмотром интерфейса. Это дорогого стоит.

Comment: Лично меня в MVC напрягает часть **Controller**, если, например, с моделлью и вьшками все ясно, то контроллер крайне туманная вещь. И пишут его, зачастую, "кто как хочет"

Comment: Ну так на том же php есть божественное `die(var_dump($this))`, которым можно в любой момент посмотреть состояние переменных. Вот с другими языками - там все совсем по-другому, хотя бы скриптовые оценивать. А то в некоторых *только* функциональный подход вообще работает)

Но пример хороший, спасибо, хотя я все равно не уверен, что mvc тут не лишний.

Comment: @Sh4dow о каком языке речь?

Да и я (типа тонко =)) намекну - для MVC **НЕ ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО** использование ооп

Comment: Эт я ответ комментировал, который "безотносительно языка и платформы". Оно интересно, но хотелось бы именно применительно к php, т.к. у него куча своих, скажем так, особенностей)

Answer (score 2):

Ругать MVC судя по одной из реализаций, это тоже самое что сказать что все люди уголовники потому что вы знакомы с одним человеком, и он уголовник. Прежде чем кого-то сбросить с лестницы, стоит почитать принципы этого подхода, и, если вы на 100% уверены что в состоянии придумать что-то лучше, либо же лучше реализовать основные принципы MVC, сделайте это! После судите!

Исторически сложилось так что я больше работал с форумами vBulletin, но вот в этом месяце пришлось поработать с новой версией IPB в основе которой уже лежат принципы MVC. Так вот, мне теперь хочется сбросить с лестницы разработчиков vBulletin. Потому что если вы напишете приложение, смешав стиль функции, классы, и каждая страница это свой php файл. Например там страница пользователя и.т.д. То вас забросают г*вном. Но вот vBulletin, это же совсем другое дело! Потому что это разработка Jelsoft Enterprises Ltd! На данный момент, глядя на инструментарий который нам дает php, я не наблюдаю чего-то более приемлемого. А наломать дров можно с любым подходом. Это не трудно.

p.s Делайте всегда качественно! Плохо само собой получается!

Comment: А вы попробуйте, как я, после джумлы с битриксом поработать)) Впечатления ровно такие же, только объекты впечатления наоборот)

Comment: Для меня лично ни первое ни второе показателем никогда не было ))). Если уже и похвалить когото, то наверно разработчиков modx не все мне там тоже нравится, но это и нормально думаю. Просто свои заскоки не более ))). Но в целом я понимаю о чем вы )))

Answer (score 1):

Если честно, мое мнение - архитектура MVC - дерьмо. Простите за резкость, но сталкиваясь с шаблонными сайтами, построенными на такой архитектуре ... хочется просто плевать, а создателя сего чуда сбросить с лестницы, либо крыши 20-этажного дома.

Лично мое мнение:

1. Если есть возможность использовать шаблоны HTML + JS (для Ajax запросов, которые будут редактировать шаблон) - используйте.
2. Практически любой код можно написать опираясь на 3 паттерна: (Фасад, Декоратор, Адаптер).
   Конечно, не везде покатит, но как практика показывает........
3. Всегда используйте ООП. Это облегчит работу тому, кто будет после Вас писать код... да и если Вы напишите хотя бы 100000 строк без ООП, потом долго будете разбирать свой же код.

Comment: Впрочем, плохо написанный ООП код Вы будете разбирать еще дольше.

Comment: WARNING! Holy war! Если строго судить - ООП не существует в большинстве языков, это просто расширение процедурного подхода...

Comment: ООП вообще-то и является расширением процедурного подхода :DDD

Comment: @Станислав Комар

Ну я с вами согласен по большинству пунктов, единственное - да, ооп тоже разумно надо использовать. Хорошо(и адекватно) обычно выглядят несколько файлов-"библиотек" с процедурами и функциями и уже чистое ооп для модулей-расширений с нативными шаблонами(безо всяких там смарти и прочего подобного). 

А, ну и mvc в js - это вообще отдельная комедия, даже не особо вменямые камрады с него плюются)

Comment: В js MVC это ИМХО бред сивой кобылы...

Answer (score 1):

> Если интересно узнать про временные рамки создания, то с помощью YII framework админку для сайта можно сделать примерно от часа до 3 часов.

Только что то все кто так пишет, скромно умалчивают что перед этим нужно потратить пару месяцев на изучение того самого YII framework

Answer (score -4):

Я, конечно, дико извиняюсь, но своё тоже добавлю:

MVC и прочие скрумы - это настоящая КАМАСУТРА для разработчиков. Также вспоминается басня товарища Крылова "Квартет".

Ну а вы - думайте сами, иметь или не иметь.