# MVC PHP (буферизированный вывод)

Tags: php

Почему надо буферизовать вывод шаблона в *mvc php*?

Почему плохо сразу использовать *include* без *ob_start*?

Answer (score 1):

Буферизация вывода - это антипаттерн, не имеющий отношения ни к MVC, ни к подключению файлов, ни к работе с командой.

Буферизация вывода позволяет предотвратить вывод и, при необходимости, сохранить его в переменную. Этим пользуются люди, которые таким образом замещают качественный шаблонизатор - они подключают файлы с выводом, с помощью буферизации сохраняют вывод и выводят его где-то после. Вместо этого необходимо использовать любой нормальный шаблонизатор (например, [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)), который значительно сократит объем кода, сделав шаблон читаемым, отделит слой View от остальных, и не станет влезать в работу интерпретатора. Использовать в качестве шаблонов PHP-файлы со вставками - это каменный век, который ведет к боли и неудобству.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы еще не участвовали в крупных проектах Трудно представить зачем нужно MVC.

Но когда работаеш командой, ты понимаеш зачем программисты придумали всякие такие технологии. И понимаеш как ими воспользоватся. Тут описание обоих технологий. Один (1) делаеш все сам в ручную. и (2) это MVC за тебя все уже сделано. Заново велосипед не мастериш.

и include() это самое худшее в работе с командой.

---

Понятие  `ob_start()` гласить "Запоминай все что обычно передается на вывод, но ничего не делай с ним" ("Start remembering everything that would normally be outputted, but don't quite do anything with it yet.")

К Примеру:

```
ob_start();
echo("Hello there!"); // Тут должно было выводится на экран/браузер
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

1. Это удобно когда возникает ошибка или что то в этом роде. Так как пока ничего не отправлено на вывод, можно перенаправить в другие стороны.
2. Это удобно если последовательность обработки и вывод отличаются. К примеру с начало нужно найти Страну, потом его города а выводе показывать наоборот. Просто перед выводом показываеш в обратном порядке.

Также полезно узнать о  `ob_start()`, `ob_get_contents()`, `ob_end_clean()` и `ob_flush()`

---

А теперь про MVC (просто прогуглил, можете узнать мнение многих)

[MVC - зачем и почему - ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/61744/mvc-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83)

[Из Хабры](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127351/)

[Тостер](https://toster.ru/q/17158)

Comment: спасибо за инфу, конечно, но по делу ничего не ответил. для чего в mvc это нужно

Comment: изменил ответ. может поможет.

Comment: Буферизовать вывод - это дикий антипаттерн